# Old MsWord file opening with junk characters

Tags: microsoft-word, characters

I want to open an old Ms Word file. The file is opening but its showing junk characters instead of the actual text. Before the file opens, the system asks me to choose some encoding. How do I open the file correctly?

Comment: try to open it with other Word-like software, either local or online

Comment: This would have been a better question had it included a sample of what the file as opened looks like.

Answer (score 1):

This issue looks like you have chosen the wrong encoding: try it with UTF-8 / UTF-16.
The characters have been obviously wrong interpreted, that's all...